# identifying an age eligible to vote, without using conditional statements

Tags: c++

Is there a way to code in C++ where it only uses functions to check if a given integer `age` is in a threshold of voting age (in my case, 18) without using conditional statement keywords (`if`, `else`)?

I tried doing it, but cannot find a solution to use it without conditional statements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it, like showing us a [mre] of your own attempt, together with a detailed description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: There is the three-way ? operator, or you could use the age to access an array and get an answer for any age (within the array bounds) from it, or you could (advanced) use the age as non-class template parameter and specialize templates according to the age. Conditions are also processed in for, while, do loops or switch case statements. You can misuse them all to just execute code depending on a condition. You can also look through the standard library for suitable functions. But, all in all, conditions are an important part of programming.

Comment: Please specify the technical problem in the title (alternative for conditions), not the application (voting age).

Comment: @Sebastian That would count as a conditional statement too

Comment: @PepijnKramer which one? Or all? I had extended the comment after first saving it.

Comment: What do you want to do when you determined if someone has a voting age? What you are looking for is called "branchless programming" and is usually not a beginners topic.

Comment: @Sebastian The three way operator. However I got the impression OP isn't completely using "conditional statement" in the way I normally would understand it. I think he means without "if" statement but I cannot be sure.

Comment: What is the condition (no pun intended) for someone to be eligible to vote? What do you want to do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a bool to an integer. When you do, `false` converts to 0, and `true` converts to 1. So you can use that to index into an array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool oldEnough(int age) { 
    return age > 18;
}

int main() { 
    static const std::vector<std::string> strings[] { 
        "You are too young to vote.\n",
        "You are old enough to vote.\n"
    };

    int age;
    std::cout << "Please enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    std::cout << strings[static_cast<int>(oldEnough(age))];
}
```

So no `if`s (even in disguise, such as `?:`).

Comment: std::array<std::string_view> would also be an option here since all your strings will be fixed at compile time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: yup--or even just `char const *strings[] ...`, if you preferred.

Comment: Yup but I try to follow the core guidelines. And these are kind of "owning" raw-pointers so I choose to use std::string_view. But is all kind of equal ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Yeah, for a case like string literals (which have static lifetime) "owning" is kind of a moot point. Just for example, even if you did use `std::array<std::string_view>`, you could easily end up with two (or more) different ones owning the same storage--exactly what ownership semantics generally tries to assure won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that returns a value, using comparison operators eg.

```
#include <iostream>

bool isVotingAge(int age) {
    return age >= 18;
}

int main() {
    int age;
    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    bool canVote = isVotingAge(age);

    if (canVote) {
        std::cout << "You are of voting age." << std::endl;
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "You are not of voting age." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. However, one could argue that there is still if..else in main.